# Edit Exceptions.plist on OSX 10.11 Beta 2 (el capitan)

Tags: macos, permissions, xcode

I am trying to edit the file `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/Exceptions.plist` (It is a binary plist) but I always receive the same error (I don't have enough permissions to do it).

I tried some ways to do it with no lock.  These are the things I tried:

1) Open this file with XCode 7 beta, I changed the value I was looking for and when I tried to save the changes I couldn't because I didn't have enough permissions

2) I ran this command `sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1 rootless 0"` in the terminal and I restarted trying to edit the file like in 1). Same error.

3) I copied the file to my desktop, I changed the value I need to change I save it.  After that, I tried remove the original file and copy the new one.  Same error.

4) I tried to unlock the file from Finder (and after that I tried to change the permissions from Terminal) but I couldn't.

I am totally lost, I don't know what else to try to edit and change that file.  Do you have any suggestion?

**UPDATE 1**
This is the output of `ls -l@AeO Exceptions.plist`

> -rw-r--r--  1 root  whell  restricted,compressed 63573 Jun 11 20:05 Exceptions.plist

**SOLUTION**

- I edited the file `/System/Library/Sandbox/rootless.conf`
- I commented the line with the path where I want to change the file
- I restarted my computer and change the file (with `sudo`)
- I edited the file `/System/Library/Sandbox/rootless.conf` again and I uncomment the line previously commented
- I restarted my computer again and voila :)

Comment: Can you run `ls -l@AeO ` (that's a lower case ell and a capital oh) on the file and on the directory it's in, so we can see how it's protected (permissions, owner/group, ACLs, file flags, etc.)? Edit/update your question with the output.

Comment: I added the output of the `ls` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I found (If anyone find a better or easier solution please post as an answer)

- I edited the file /System/Library/Sandbox/rootless.conf
- I commented the line with the path where I want to change the file
- I restarted my computer and change the file (with sudo)
- I edited the file /System/Library/Sandbox/rootless.conf again and I
  uncomment the line previously commented
- I restarted my computer again and voila :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
sudo vi /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/Exceptions.plist
```

Well, that would work if it's a text plist. If it's a binary plist, you'll have other troubles.

In that case, after editing it like you did in attempt #3, try this:

```
sudo cp ~/Desktop/Exceptions.plist /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/Exceptions.plist
```

Comment: It is a binary plist.  I forgot to mention that, I'll edit my question.

Comment: About the commands, all the commands I ran were with `sudo`.  I think the problem is related with the `rootless` feature in OSX El Capitan.